# DocumentText property changed without DocumentComplete event in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm using WebBrowser for parse webpages with javascript and
I've been try to find what I need on page by using
DocumentCompleted event and checking Document property in WebBrowser by HtmlElement inner text
(i know that it's appear after some time while page loading).
something like that:

```
  private void WebDocCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        parseWebbrowserDocumentPropertyFunc(); // wich set the content value to true
        if (!content)
                return;
        }
```

so, when I start debug code for execution, i see one thing: 
tag (HtmlElement) appear in webbroser, after webbroser stops fire DocumentCompleted event.
I mean that there is no DocumentCompleted event happend, but DocumentText property still change.

Ok, i've been done my work by using timer + Application.DoEvents()
everything is fine, but parsing process begin to take a lot of time, because - i dont know why.

And now I think that Application.DoEvents() is not good solution and i still want to use DocumentCompleted event, 
but i cant find some inforation about:

Why DocumentText property changes happend without fire DocumentCompleted event

or

What can I use to wait tag i needed on a page instead timer

timer sets to 200ms

Answer (score 0):

The `DocumentCompleted` event does fire every time a frame is loaded. So obviously the document is different every time it fires.
You can add an additional check in your event. The `ReadyState` only gets set when the whole document is completed.

```
private void WebDocCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (yourBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        return;
    parseWebbrowserDocumentPropertyFunc();
    }
```

Comment: is it exist way to catch changes of document without timer?

Comment: What do you mean without a timer? There's no timer involved in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Why DocumentText property changes happend without fire
>   DocumentCompleted event

This is because your timer working too fast (200ms) and `DocumentComplete` event can not get in time. Try to stop you timer until `DocumentComplete` not fired.

```
private void DocumentComplete(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _Timer.Start();
    if (yourBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        return;
    parseWebbrowserDocumentPropertyFunc();
}
private void parseWebbrowserDocumentPropertyFunc()
{
    _Timer.Stop();
    //something parse.....
}
```